# How to add up strings in array

Tags: java, arrays, string

2^1000 = 2147483647, now i want to add up all the individual numbers in the answer (e.g. 2+1+4+7+4...)
This is my code but im getting the answer as -10. This is my logic:
Convert 2147483647 to string
Convert that string to char
make a char array and put all the char into that array
make a int array and put all those chars into that array and then add up the elements

My code

```
   int total = 0;
    int x = (int) Math.pow(2, 1000);        
    System.out.println("2^1000 = " + x);

    String power = Integer.toString(x);

    ArrayList<Integer> powstoint = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //From string to char
    char[] stringtochar = power.toCharArray();
    for(int b = 0; b<stringtochar.length;b++){
        powstoint.add(b, power.indexOf(Integer.parseInt(power)));
        total = total + powstoint.get(b);
    }
    System.out.println(total);

    }
```

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that your integer overflows, the problem is that `power.indexOf(Integer.parseInt(power))` will always returns `-1` (see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29))
.

Since you have 10 digits in your number, you got as output -10.

To achieve what you want, use [`Character.getNumericValue(char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29).

```
char[] stringtochar = power.toCharArray();
for(int b = 0; b<stringtochar.length;b++){
    powstoint.add(b, Character.getNumericValue(stringtochar[b]));
    total = total + powstoint.get(b);
}
```

There's no need of using a `List` in your program. You can directly perform the sum like this :

```
for(char c : power.toCharArray()){
    total += Character.getNumericValue(c);
}
```

---

It seems like you're doing the Euler project problem #16 :

Use `BigDecimal` to store your number and avoid overflow :

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(2, 1000));
```

Then to get the char array, use the same procedure :

```
char[] array = x.toString().toCharArray();
```

Comment: Alright thanks for your help. One of the things i dont understand in programming is the amount of methods you have to learn. Im still a beginner and I haven't heard of bigdecimal before nor the Character.getNumericValue(char ch) method.

Comment: @Tloz More you program, more you'll have to look at the API doc and more you'll learn. This site is also very helpful to learn new stuff. =)

Answer (score 1):

`2^anything` can't be an odd number.

`2^1000` is much more than `2147483647`.

Integer overflow strikes again. `int` can not fit `2^1000`.

Answer (score 0):

The [largest possible int value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is `214783647`, which is `2^31-1`.

What's happening is `2^1000` is larger than the largest possible value of `int`, so it just makes it the largest value (`214783647`).